# How can I setup manual approval to proceed in AWS CodePipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline

I wish to create the following AWS CodePipeline process

1. Developers push code to GitHub
2. CodeDeploy deploys code to Test environment EC2
3. Test engineer tests the web app on EC2
4. Test engineer manually approves this revision
5. CodeDeploy deploys code to Live environment EC2

My problem is in step 4 and 5, how can I make the codepipeline wait for manual approval (step 4) and then if approved, automatically proceeds to deploying next stage (step 5)

Thanks

Comment: any help please ???!!!

Comment: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=220702&tstart=0

Comment: Support for manual approval has now been added to AWS CodePipeline https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/07/aws-codepipeline-adds-manual-approval-actions/

Answer (score 2):

To address your problem with Step 4 and 5 this can be accomplished 2 ways:

1) AWS has added the ability to add a manual approval step via the console:
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/07/aws-codepipeline-adds-manual-approval-actions/

- Open existing CodePipeline
- Edit CodePipeline
- Select the pencil icon [image]on the Stage you want the Manual approval in
- Click [image] then add this type of action:

[image]

2) ManualApproval can also be added to a CodePipeline CloudFormation Template Action like this:

```
- InputArtifacts: []
      Name: !Join ["",[!Ref GitHubRepository, "-prd-approval"]]
      ActionTypeId:
        Category: Approval
        Owner: AWS
        Version: '1'
        Provider: Manual
      OutputArtifacts: []
      Configuration:
        NotificationArn: !Ref ManualApprovalNotification
        ExternalEntityLink: OutputTestUrl
      RunOrder: 3
```

Comment: is there any API to fetch the result/status of this approval?